# Add page number with hyper link next to the abbreviation?

Tags: chapters, acronyms, thesis

I want to add the page number with a hyperlink next to the abbreviation as in the picture, by modifying the following template :
[Master thesis template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-for-a-masters-slash-doctoral-thesis/mkzrzktcbzfl?fbclid=IwAR2bPvmutMNXnbjrJMhFCoUt_G5CMA6vBrdoReblu11Aup9MwOMK28IfQ6o)

The abbreviation should look like the following:
[image: example]

Besides, I would like to modify all the headings in the previous template such as chapter names, contents, figures to be centered surrounded by lines, like the picture:
[image: Chapters Headings]